# prepareForSegue switch with UINavigationController… a better way?

Tags: swift, uinavigationcontroller, switch-statement, segue

I have a couple of segues presenting modal view controllers.

```
class ProfileViewController: UIViewController {
    func configure(profile: Profile) { 
        // Some ProfileViewController specific config
    }
}

class SettingsViewController: UIViewController {
   func configure(settings: Settings) { 
        // Some SettingsViewController specific config
    }
}
```

So here's some pretty standard code we've all written many times…

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    switch segue.destination {
    case let nav as UINavigationController:
        switch nav.topViewController {
        case let pvc as ProfileViewController:

            pvc.configure(profile: profile)
        case let svc as SettingsViewController:

            svc.configure(settings: settings)
        default:
            break
        }
    default:
        break
    }
}
```

I've also tried it this way…

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    switch segue.destination {
    case let nav as UINavigationController
        where nav.topViewController is ProfileViewController:

        (nav.topViewController as! ProfileViewController).configure(profile: profile)
    case let nav as UINavigationController
        where nav.topViewController is SettingsViewController:

        (nav.topViewController as! SettingsViewController).configure(settings: settings)
    default:
        break
    }
}
```

But what I'd like to do is a combination of the two…

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    switch segue.destination {
    case let nav as UINavigationController
        where let pvc = nav.topViewController as ProfileViewController:

        pvc.configure(profile: profile)
    case let nav as UINavigationController
        where let svc = nav.topViewController as SettingsViewController:

        svc.configure(settings: settings)
    default:
        break
    }
}
```

but obviously that won't compile. Has anyone come across a better pattern for this?

---

*UPDATE*

Expanding on @Serj's answer below…

```
extension UIStoryboardSegue {
    var destinationNavTopViewController: UIViewController? {
        return (destination as? UINavigationController)?.topViewController
    }
}
```

then

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    switch (segue.destination, destinationNavTopViewController) {
    case let (_, pvc as ProfileViewController):

        pvc.configure(profile: profile)
    case let (_, svc as SettingsViewController):

        svc.configure(settings: settings)
    case let (ovc as OtherViewController, _):
        ovc.configure…
    default:
        break
    }
}
```

Comment: I would suggest having a base `UIViewController` which has `configure` method to be overridden, or a protocol like `ConfigurableController` which conforms to `configure`, and the same for the `UINavigationController`. If creating multiple classes/protocols works for you, I can convert this into an answer.

Comment: Sorry, I should have been clearer - these configure methods are different per view controller, take different parameters etc. Also, with Swift I feel we should be moving away from "Base" view controllers. And  the real point of the question is about how the switch is handled.

Comment: What about `if let nav as UINavigationController, let pvc = nav.topViewController as ProfileViewController { .. } else if ...` instead of a switch statement?

Comment: An `if let` would certainly work, and it removes the need for the `default` case.

Comment: Your first variant avoids the repetition `as UINavigationController`, alternatively `if let` for the outer matching and `switch` for the inner. If you *know* that the segue goes to a UINavigationController then you can also force cast. And if you *know* that the switch is exhaustive then I would call `fatalError()` in the default case, to detect programming errors early. – Just my 2 ct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When asking this question of How-to we can consider two cases:

1. The specific use case on what you want to achieve
2. The more general use-case of `switch` statements

Now for the specific use case it seems you only want to act on switching on the `segue.destination` when you have a navigation controller. You can easily achieve this with a `if let` or `guard let` like the following:

```
guard let navigationController = segue.destination as? UINavigationController else { return }
guard let topController = navigationController.topViewController else { return }
switch topController {
  case let profileViewController as ProfileViewController:
    print("Do something for profile view controller")
  default:
    break
}
```

Now the second case which is more general and about how to be able to have both variables available in the switch statement. The answer is tuples. For example I'm going to provide an example from the Apple's documentation and then provide an example for your specific use case.

```
let anotherPoint = (2, 0)
switch anotherPoint {
case (let x, 0):
    print("on the x-axis with an x value of \(x)")
case (0, let y):
    print("on the y-axis with a y value of \(y)")
case let (x, y):
    print("somewhere else at (\(x), \(y))")
}
```

Now for the example on how to achieve the above with your use-case be warned its an ugly example could be improved but gets the point across:

```
switch (segue.destination, (segue.destination as? UINavigationController)?.topViewController) {
case (let nav as UINavigationController, let viewController as ProfileViewController):
    return
// Maybe the destination wasn't a nav maybe it was the sign in view controller and you don't care about the second variable
case (let signInController as SignInViewController, let _):
    return
default:
    return
}
```

This is the power of switch statements being able to switch over Tuples so easily. I hope my example answers your question. I tried covering all parts of the question with all the ambiguities.

Comment: Interesting - I hadn't considered switching on `(segue.destination as? UINavigationController)?.topViewController` as well. Maybe even nicer with an extension on `UIStoryboardSegue`…  `extension UIStoryboardSegue {
    var navDestinationTopViewController: UIViewController? {
        return (destination as? UINavigationController)?.topViewController
    }
}`

Comment: @AshleyMills I think that would work very well and clean up the mess I made above :)!

Comment: @AshleyMills better to use `if let` as martin suggest . you can also use guard let  as Serj suggest in first block , don't mess your code with tuple